# msrest.exceptions.ValidationError: Parameter 'resource_group_name' must conform to the following pattern: '^[-\\w\\._\\(\\)]+$'

Tags: python, exception, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-group, azure-cloud-shell

sathish@Azure:~/quickstart/python-docs-hello-world$ az webapp up -n appname
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:

```
Parameter 'resource_group_name' must conform to the following pattern: '^[-\\w\\._\\(\\)]+$'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 206, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 326, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 384, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 375, in _run_job
    cmd_copy.exception_handler(ex)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/commands.py", line 54, in _polish_bad_errors
    raise ex
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 354, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 145, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 451, in default_command_handler
    return op(**command_args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 2313, in webapp_up
    _create_new_rg = should_create_new_rg(cmd, default_rg, rg_name, is_linux)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/_create_util.py", line 282, in should_create_new_rg
    elif (_check_resource_group_exists(cmd, rg_name) and
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/_create_util.py", line 86, in _check_resource_group_exists
    return rcf.resource_groups.check_existence(rg_name)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/mgmt/resource/resources/v2018_05_01/operations/resource_groups_operations.py", line 61, in check_existence
    'resourceGroupName': self._serialize.url("resource_group_name", resource_group_name, 'str', max_length=90, min_length=1, pattern=r'^[-\w\._\(\)]+$'),
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 592, in url
    data = self.validate(data, name, required=True, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 672, in validate
    raise ValidationError(key, name, value)
msrest.exceptions.ValidationError: Parameter 'resource_group_name' must conform to the following pattern: '^[-\\w\\._\\(\\)]+$'.

To open an issue, please run: 'az feedback'
```

Comment: Whatever resource group you had specified in the request to azure does not follow what azure is expecting. It even told you what regex the name must conform to. `^[-\\w\\._\\(\\)]+$`

Comment: are any other solutions there? Because resource group name is matching with default regex pattern. Kindly provide any other solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, but resolved it by removing the quotes around the resource group name. Silly mistake on my behalf, but may be the issue here.

e.g. use `az group create -n my-groupname-rg -l northeurope`
rather than: e.g. use `az group create -n 'my-groupname-rg' -l 'northeurope'`

Answer (score 0):

For resource group name, you should take a look at [Naming rules and restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions#naming-rules-and-restrictions):

[image]

Comment: Hello, if the answer helps, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SathishKannan, here is a similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9050), can you try to [install the cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) locally, then use local azure cli for this test?